# Change the column type from date to minutes (only minutes and seconds are display)

Tags: r, date, format, numeric

I wanna change my column from date to decimal numbers (but I want display minutes and seconds like that : MM.SS). My column looks like this:

[image]

I wrote the code but as a result I got an error.

```
XYZ$Start <- if(format(XYZ$Start, format="%H") = 1) {
  as.numeric(format(XYZ$Start, format="%M.%S"))+60
} else {
  as.numeric(format(XYZ$Start, format="%M.%S"))
}
```

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Try using `ifelse()` instead of `if()`.  Also `as.numeric()` calls are not helping.